# I can't view my website after uploading files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I uploaded my site backup files from another domain, after extracting the content and setting up the database I am getting this error message:

This page isn’t working is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500.

these are the errors I am getting from apache error logs:

I have deleted the cache folder from the previous site

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/studypal/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 957
mmap cache can't open /home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php - Permission denied (pid 18797)
mmap cache can't open /home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php - Permission denied (pid 18797)
mmap cache can't open /home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Configure/PhpReader.php - Permission denied (pid 18797)
mmap cache can't open /home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php - Permission denied (pid 18797)
PHP Warning: include(/home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/studyconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/studyconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 547
PHP Fatal error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/studyconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 957
```

Comment: It seems that some of the files are not readable, because they do not have the correct access rights.

Comment: so i should make them writeable by changing the permission?

Comment: At least readable. Check the permissions of the file `/home/payconnet/public_html/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php`

Comment: it's 0644  and I have changed it to 0755